# touchesShouldCancelInContentView not called on uibutton

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I'm working on a new Swift project with a UITableViewController. I have the problem that buttons in cells respond with a delay, a familiar issue. I have dealt with this before in an older project by subclassing the tableView and overriding touchesShouldCancelInContentView.

This time it doesn't seem to work. I checked canCancelContentTouched and unchecked delaysContentTouches in storyboard, but I did it here in code as well to be sure. I added some prints to find out what's going on. When I touch a button (short or long) I don't get anything in the console. The button's action gets triggered though. Touching outside a button shows the touchesBegin and touchesEnded.

```
import UIKit
class MyTableView: UITableView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        print("initTV")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delaysContentTouches = false
        self.canCancelContentTouches = true
    }

    override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView!) -> Bool {
        print(view)
        if view.isKindOfClass(UIButton) {
            return true
        }
        return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("touchesBegan")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("touchesEnded")
    }
}
```

Has anyone tries this in Swift with Storyboard yet?